# Change size of image in flutter native splash screen package

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-layout, flutter-dependencies

i recently imported native splash screen package in my flutter project. But when i start the app, image in there is so small. Is there any solution please to increase size of image?

[This is the splash screen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kVNoQ.png)

and i also add my pubspec.yaml code

```
flutter_native_splash:
 color: "#ffffff"
 image: assets/nakupnylistlogo.png
 android: true
 ios: true
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I just changed size of image. Have a nice day.

Comment: Have a nice day too!

Comment: Have a nice day too!

Comment: Have a nice day too!

Comment: Have a nice day too!

Comment: Have a nice day too!

Comment: Have a nice day too!

Comment: Have a nice day too!

Comment: Have a nice day too!

Comment: Have a nice day too!

Comment: Have a nice day too!

Comment: Have a nice day too!

Comment: Have a nice day too!

Comment: Have a nice day too!

Comment: Have a nice day too!

Comment: Have a nice day too!

Comment: Have a nice day too!